# Asyncio code show incremental number of params each time it's called

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

The following code is about executing a list of functions over a table. Just like a pipeline does. The list is passed as an array of OrderedDicts. The OrderedDict not only has the list of functions to be called, but also de arguments for each of the functions. The functions are all about CSV data wrangling. It's a wrapper of the pandas library. The problem is that each time a I call the handler (simulating concurrent jobs) the functions prints its message one more time than previous handler() call.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime
import logging, time, asyncio
#import configargparse
from funciones import file, csv_tools


p = [
     OrderedDict([
        ['file.read_csv', {
                'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/hw_25000.csv',
                "header": 0,
                'sep': ', ',
        }],
        ['csv_tools.show_column_names', {}],
        ['csv_tools.show_data_size', {}], 
    ]),
    OrderedDict([
        ['file.read_csv', {
                'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/hw_200.csv',
                "header": 0,
                'sep': ', ',
        }],
        ['csv_tools.show_column_names', {}],
        ['csv_tools.show_data_size', {}],        
    ]),
    OrderedDict([
        ['file.read_csv', {
                'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/snakes_count_10000.csv',
                "header": 0,
                'sep': ', ',
        }],
        ['csv_tools.show_column_names', {}],
        ['csv_tools.show_data_size', {}], 
    ])]



LOG_LEVEL=logging.DEBUG


def set_logger(task_id):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(task_id)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(funcName)10s(): %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, {'task_id': task_id})
    return logger


async def handler(task_id, params):
    try:        
        #TODO montar mecanismo de subscripcion a eventos para comenzar
        logger = set_logger(task_id)
        logger.debug(f"parametros recibidos: {params}")
        s = time.perf_counter()
        buffer = None
        for func in params:
            logger.debug("executing: {}".format(func))
            f = eval(func)
            buffer = await f(buffer, params[func], logger)
        elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
        print(f"Fin: ({elapsed:0.2f} secs)")
        #TODO lanzar evento de fin
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Se ha producido un fallo:")
        #TODO lanzar evento de fallo
        raise ex

async def main(p):

    await asyncio.gather(
            handler(1000, p[0]),
            handler(20000, p[1]),
            handler(30000, p[2]))


asyncio.run(main(p))
```

When is executed shows incremental number of prompts as follows:

```
2019-03-31 17:35:17,437 [DEBUG] 1000 try.py:64    handler(): parametros recibidos: OrderedDict([('file.read_csv', {'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/hw_25000.csv', 'header': 0, 'sep': ', '}), ('csv_tools.show_column_names', {}), ('csv_tools.show_data_size', {})])
2019-03-31 17:35:17,437 [DEBUG] 1000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: file.read_csv
2019-03-31 17:35:20,702 [DEBUG] 1000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_column_names
2019-03-31 17:35:20,703 [INFO] 1000 csv_tools.py:14 show_column_names(): ['"Index"' '"Height(Inches)"' '"Weight(Pounds)"']
2019-03-31 17:35:20,703 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:64    handler(): parametros recibidos: OrderedDict([('file.read_csv', {'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/hw_200.csv', 'header': 0, 'sep': ', '}), ('csv_tools.show_column_names', {}), ('csv_tools.show_data_size', {})])
2019-03-31 17:35:20,703 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:64    handler(): parametros recibidos: OrderedDict([('file.read_csv', {'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/hw_200.csv', 'header': 0, 'sep': ', '}), ('csv_tools.show_column_names', {}), ('csv_tools.show_data_size', {})])
2019-03-31 17:35:20,703 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: file.read_csv
2019-03-31 17:35:20,703 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: file.read_csv
2019-03-31 17:35:21,218 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_column_names
2019-03-31 17:35:21,218 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_column_names
2019-03-31 17:35:21,218 [INFO] 20000 csv_tools.py:14 show_column_names(): ['"Index"' 'Height(Inches)"' '"Weight(Pounds)"']
2019-03-31 17:35:21,218 [INFO] 20000 csv_tools.py:14 show_column_names(): ['"Index"' 'Height(Inches)"' '"Weight(Pounds)"']
2019-03-31 17:35:21,219 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:64    handler(): parametros recibidos: OrderedDict([('file.read_csv', {'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/snakes_count_10000.csv', 'header': 0, 'sep': ', '}), ('csv_tools.show_column_names', {}), ('csv_tools.show_data_size', {})])
2019-03-31 17:35:21,219 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:64    handler(): parametros recibidos: OrderedDict([('file.read_csv', {'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/snakes_count_10000.csv', 'header': 0, 'sep': ', '}), ('csv_tools.show_column_names', {}), ('csv_tools.show_data_size', {})])
2019-03-31 17:35:21,219 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:64    handler(): parametros recibidos: OrderedDict([('file.read_csv', {'path': 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/snakes_count_10000.csv', 'header': 0, 'sep': ', '}), ('csv_tools.show_column_names', {}), ('csv_tools.show_data_size', {})])
2019-03-31 17:35:21,219 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: file.read_csv
2019-03-31 17:35:21,219 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: file.read_csv
2019-03-31 17:35:21,219 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: file.read_csv
2019-03-31 17:35:22,570 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_column_names
2019-03-31 17:35:22,570 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_column_names
2019-03-31 17:35:22,570 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_column_names
2019-03-31 17:35:22,570 [INFO] 30000 csv_tools.py:14 show_column_names(): ['"Game Number"' '"Game Length"']
2019-03-31 17:35:22,570 [INFO] 30000 csv_tools.py:14 show_column_names(): ['"Game Number"' '"Game Length"']
2019-03-31 17:35:22,570 [INFO] 30000 csv_tools.py:14 show_column_names(): ['"Game Number"' '"Game Length"']
2019-03-31 17:35:30,711 [DEBUG] 1000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:30,711 [DEBUG] 1000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:30,711 [DEBUG] 1000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:30,712 [INFO] 1000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 25000, columnas: 3
2019-03-31 17:35:30,712 [INFO] 1000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 25000, columnas: 3
2019-03-31 17:35:30,712 [INFO] 1000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 25000, columnas: 3
Fin: (13.28 secs)
2019-03-31 17:35:31,220 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:31,220 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:31,220 [DEBUG] 20000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:31,221 [INFO] 20000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 200, columnas: 3
2019-03-31 17:35:31,221 [INFO] 20000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 200, columnas: 3
2019-03-31 17:35:31,221 [INFO] 20000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 200, columnas: 3
Fin: (10.52 secs)
2019-03-31 17:35:32,573 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:32,573 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:32,573 [DEBUG] 30000 try.py:68    handler(): executing: csv_tools.show_data_size
2019-03-31 17:35:32,574 [INFO] 30000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 10000, columnas: 2
2019-03-31 17:35:32,574 [INFO] 30000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 10000, columnas: 2
2019-03-31 17:35:32,574 [INFO] 30000 csv_tools.py:37 show_data_size(): Filas: 10000, columnas: 2
Fin: (11.35 secs)
```

Every time I call the function handler() it prints one more time its message. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!!

The problem is that each time the set_logger function is called, it add a new handler to the logger. The solution is straitforward. Just change the set_logger to remove previous hanlders before adding the new one:

```
def set_logger(task_id):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    for h in logger.handlers:        
        logger.removeHandler(h)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)7s  %(task_id)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(funcName)10s(): %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, {'task_id': task_id})
    return logger
```